# How can I make multiple http calls on multiple array properties of an object in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

I'm learning Angular and I'm still trying to wrap my head around observables.

In my app I make an API call which returns a Project object, which has (among other properties) an object array property called "folders" and an object array property called "photos."  Each photo in turn has a property named "referenceImageUrl" and one named "capturedImageUrl" each of which contain a url to an image on the internet.

What I want to do is after downloading the project, download all the reference images and captured images it contains. I have figured out how to download the project and (I think) how to then make https calls for each image for one of the image types. What I cannot figure out is how to make two separate http calls for each image, as well as how to loop the folders and images of the downloaded project separately.

Here is the non-functional code I have so far:

```
return this.http.get(getProjectUrl, { headers: headers })
  .timeout(30000)
  .map(this.extractProjectData)
  .do(project => {
    return this.projectRepository.saveProject(project);
  })
  .mergeMap(project => { return Observable.from(project.photos) })
  .mergeMap(photo => {

      //Download each photo and save the photo to the database
      // (returns an Observable<Photo>)
      return this.photoService.downloadCapturedPhoto(photo);

      //QUESTION: How can I also download the reference photos
      //          using this.this.photoService.downloadReferencePhoto(photo)?

  })
  .mergeMap(project => {

    //QUESTION: How can I get back to working with the project 
                here so I can loop folders, assuming that 
                matrixItemService.downloadCapturedPhoto() does not 
                return the project object
  })
  .catch(this.handleErrors);
```

**Edit:**

After doing some more reading and looking over the helpful recipes link that Martin posted, I've now come up with this:

```
return this.http.get(getProjectUrl, { headers: headers })
  .map(this.extractProjectData)
  .do(project => {
    downloadedProject = project;
    return this.projectRepository.saveProject(project);
  })
  .mergeMap(project => { return Observable.from(project.photos) })
  .mergeMap(photo => {
      //Download each photo and save the photo to the database
          return this.photoService.downloadReferencePhoto(photo)
                 .concatMap(photoWithReferenceImage => { return this.photoService.downloadCapturedPhoto(photoWithReferenceImage); })
                 .concatMap(photoWithBothImages => { return this.matrixItemRepository.savePhoto(photoWithBothImages); });
      })
  .mergeMap(project => {
    //QUESTION: How can I get back to working with the project 
            here so I can loop folders
  })
  .catch(this.handleErrors);
```

I still can't understand how to "get back" to working with the project after the photos download so that I can then work with its folders.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/8247/common-recipes/27973/sending-multiple-parallel-http-requests#t=201705082301056342059

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured this out.  The key concept I was not grasping was that I can declare variables that reference observables and subjects just like any other function, and that I could declare a new observable stream directly from an array.

Here's my working solution to my question: this downloads a project, then declares two separate observables that save folders and download and save reference images.  It then forkJoins these two observables and returns the resulting observable, so that both streams run once the calling code subscribes to the outer observable.

```
return this.authHttp.get(getProjectUrl, { headers: headers })
      .timeout(30000)
      .map(this.extractProjectData)
      .do(extractedProject => {
        return this.projectRepository.saveProject(extractedProject)
        .then(() => { project = extractedProject; });
  })
  .mergeMap(() => {

    totalPhotoCount = project.photos.length;

    let folderWork = Observable.from(project.folders)
      .concatMap((folder: Folder) => {
        return this.matrixItemService.saveFolder(folder);
      });

    let photoWork = Observable.from(project.photos)
      .mergeMap((photo: Photo) => {
        return this.matrixItemService.saveProjectPhoto(photo)
          .then(() => {
            ++completedPhotoCount;
            this.minorProgressSource.next(`Downloading photo ${completedPhotoCount} of ${totalPhotoCount}`);
          });
      }, undefined, 3); //3 = concurrent downloads and saves

    return Observable.forkJoin(folderWork, photoWork);


  })
  .catch(this.handleErrors);
```

Answer (score -4):

I don't know Angular 2, but if you want to make multiple http calls at once, there is a new $.when in the latest JQuery, check it out?